grouping in useMaterialReactTable initialState not updated
New to React/typescript
I have created a generic SearchTypeSelection and based on that a datatable is loaded with grouping based on search type using following code
<Select id="searching" value={props.searchType} onChange={handleSearchTypeChange} label="Search with"> 
{props.fields.map((field:string) => <MenuItem value={field}>{mapColumn[field]}</MenuItem>)} 
</Select>

<DataTable data={data} columns={OrderColumns} columnVisibility={orderVisible} group={searchType}></DataTable>

to list down multiple search criteria - set to const fields=['name','age','subject']. The default for searchType is set to 'name' using useState('name').
the onChange function is as follows
const handleSearchTypeChange = (e:any) => {
    props.setSearchType(e.target.value);
  };

In another file, I am create a customised datatable using useMaterialReactTable where I create the constant as follows,
const DataTable =<C extends MRT_RowData> ({columns,data,columnVisibility, group}:DataTableProps<C>) => {

const table = useMaterialReactTable({
    columns,
    data,
    columnFilterDisplayMode: "popover",
    enableGlobalFilter: false,
    enableGrouping:true,
    initialState: {
      columnVisibility,
      grouping:[group],
      expanded: true,
      
    },});

}

The default state of the grouping is set to 'name'
enter image description here
But when I select age in the drop down from MenuItem the grouping still stays as 'name'.
I am not sure if the constant table is loaded after the the const DataTable is loaded (sync-async issue)
Appreciate any guidance
